# How to use the value of a variable as a variable itself?

Tags: variables, powershell, nested

i am trying to code in powershell where it needs i use a value of a variable as a variable itself ; is there a proper syntax to do it?

here is the example;

```
$color = "red"
$red = 1

how can i obtain the value of 1? $($color) $"$color" etc give out the errors.
```

I can explain more regarding the issue i am working with if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax isn't very concise, but you can use the [`Get-Variable` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849899.aspx):

```
Get-Variable -Name $color -ValueOnly
```

...or simply...

```
gv $color -ValueOnly
```